# How can I turn an AS2 snow effect into a AS3 snow effect?

Tags: actionscript-3

So I manage to find a snow effect that I like and wanted to use it but I realized it was in AS2 and I need it to be in AS3. Since there isn't a small difference between AS2 and AS3 I'm here to find some  in these matter.

As you can see in the fla provided I also want to control the wind and speed by buttons.

Here is a link to the AS2 snow effect: http://www.freeactionscript.com/download/realistic-snow-fall-snowflake-effect.zip

This is the code in AS2:

```
//settings
var speed:Number = 2;
var wind:Number = -2;
var movieWidth:Number = 550;
var movieHeight:Number = 400;

createSnow(_root, 100);


function createSnow(container:MovieClip, numberOfFlakes:Number):Void 
{
//run a for loop based on numberOfFlakes
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfFlakes; i++) 
{       
    //set temporary variable and attach snowflake to it from the library
    var tempFlake:MovieClip = container.attachMovie("snow_mc",  "snow"+container.getNextHighestDepth(), container.getNextHighestDepth());

    //variables that will modify the falling snow
    tempFlake.r = 1+Math.random()*speed;
    tempFlake.k = -Math.PI+Math.random()*Math.PI;
    tempFlake.rad = 0;

    //giving each snowflake unique characteristics
    var randomScale:Number = random(50)+50;
    tempFlake._xscale = randomScale;
    tempFlake._yscale = randomScale
    tempFlake._alpha = random(100)+50;
    tempFlake._x = random(movieWidth);
    tempFlake._y = random(movieHeight);

    //give the flake an onEnterFrame function to constantly update its    properties
    tempFlake.onEnterFrame = function() 
    {
        //update flake position
        this.rad += (this.k / 180) * Math.PI;
        this._x -= Math.cos(this.rad)+wind;
        this._y += speed;

        //if flake out of bounds, move to other side of screen
        if (this._y >= movieHeight) {
            this._y = -5;
        }
        if (this._x >= movieWidth) 
        {
            this._x = 1
        }
        if (this._x <= 0) 
        {
            this._x = movieWidth - 1;
        }
    }
}
}

//buttons
//wind
left_btn.onRelease = function()
{
wind = 2;
}
none_btn.onRelease = function()
{
wind = 0;
}
right_btn.onRelease = function()
{
wind = -2;
}
//speed
slow_btn.onRelease = function()
{
speed = .5;
}
normal_btn.onRelease = function()
{
speed = 1
}
fast_btn.onRelease = function()
{
speed = 3
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be really quite similar.

The first thing would be, instead of:

```
var tempFlake:MovieClip = container.attachMovie("snow_mc",  "snow"+...
```

you want something like:

```
var tempFlake = new snow_mc();
container.addChild(tempFlake);
```

Then convert all the property names such as _x etc to their AS3 equivalents (no underscore, scaleX in place f _xscale etc), `Math.random() * 50` in place of `random(50)`.

Replace all `onRelease` with `addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function() {})`

Finally instead of `tempFlake.onEnterFrame` you'll need one frame loop something like:

```
function onFrame(event: Event): void {
   foreach(var child: MovieClip in container) {
      child.rad += ... etc
   }
}
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrame);
```

These steps should be sufficient to get it working as AS3. Once it's running, you could go further to make it *more AS3* by creating a SnowFlake class that encapsulates all the properties and updates for one snowflake.